Trigger Azure Function by custom cron expressions
I have an app built on AWS. One feature build on AWS Event Bridge Schedulers. This allows my users to create their schedules for running their jobs. Each schedule is a cron expression that triggers a special AWS Lambda function with a specific payload. Users can create/edit/delete their schedules. Example:
user A --> schedule 1 --> run LambdaFunction(payload_1)
       --> schedule 2 --> run LambdaFunction(payload_2)

user B --> schedule 3 --> run LambdaFunction(payload_3)

The function code is the same, the difference is only in the payload attached to each schedule.
I need to migrate this to Azure. I researched documentation and found that functions can be run by cron expression, but this expression is hardcoded and I can't have multiple expressions simultaneously. Example from doc:
const { app } = require('@azure/functions');

app.timer('timerTrigger1', {
    schedule: '0 */5 * * * *',
    handler: (myTimer, context) => {
        context.log('Timer function processed request.');
    },
});

I found the same question asked 2 years ago and by that time there was no solution. The proposed solution is to create and delete a function for each user and the schedule is creepy.
Also, I found Logic app in Azure but it allows only one cron expression.
Does Azure have the same feature as AWS?

I can only think of workarounds, which isn't what you want really. But for example: you could have a datastore of CRON expressions for each user, and then a timer job that runs every minute and checks against the datastore. If a user's CRON matches the current time, you would execute their task (or preferably, enqueue a job for a Queue Trigger Function, in case there are too many user CRONs to execute in your main Function.)
